Pass a command line argument to the new terminal window that is about to be launched?
I am trying to figure out how to launch new terminal window and pass a command line to be executed by the new terminals shell (PowerShell 7)
The following works, a new terminal window, with Pwsh as its shell opens, and get-childItem is executed:
wt pwsh -c get-childitem

But I want to choose what windows terminal profile to use for the new terminal window, rather than the generic Pwsh executable.
I tried using -p (-profile) and specifying my profile name:
wt -p my_profile -c get-childitems

This causes windows terminal to show a dialog box with an error:
The following argument was not expected: -c Run with --help for more information.

Running the following works just fine, the new window with the profile launches:
wt -p my_profile

Is this even possible?

In profile configuration you can specify pwsh executable with command to execute
